# Calendar - странное поведение

Tags: java, android, sdk

Есть у меня метод, который должен прибавлять к выбранной дате несколько дней, выглядит он так

```
private String changeDate(int addDays) {
    Calendar calendar = mCalendar;
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, addDays);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String date = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    return date;
}
```

где `mCalendar` — глобальная переменная типа `Calendar`. Суть в том, что при каждом выполнении метода `mCalendar` тоже почему-то прибавляет к себе то количество дней, хотя в коде я прибавляю дни только к переменной `calendar`. В чем может быть проблема, есть ли с типом `Calendar` в Android SDK какие то подводные камни?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переменные `сalendar` и `mCalendar` имеют одну и ту же ссылку. И если вы меняете одну из них, меняется и другая. Это особенности java, а не Android.

UPDATE: Замените

```
Calendar calendar = mCalendar;
```

на

```
Calendar calendar = (Calendar)mCalendar.clone();
```

Comment: Хах, все на столько просто... Не подскажите тогда, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: @Александр Ответ дополнен.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: @Александр Не за что:)